# For what reason are the published segment altitudes (circled in red) relevevant and ever used by flight crews flying this STAR?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, ifr-navigation, sid-star

On the HLYWD ONE Standard Terminal Arrival (STAR) into KLAX (Los Angeles International Airport) there are altitudes (circled in red on the images below) published on its "Transition" routes and its "Arrival" route that would appear to be similar to Minimum Enroute Altitudes (MEA's). On the Transition routes, for example, the altitude published is FL190, which seems a bit high for obstruction clearance and signal reception requirements based on how an MEA is defined.

**Questions:**

1. When would these altitudes ever be relevant and used by a flight crew, assuming a (Descend Via) clearance for the HLYWD ONE STAR was issued?
2. Would these altitudes ever be relevant if the flight crew lost communication prior to beginning this STAR?

[image]

[image]

Comment: On an *approach procedure* chart, those numbers would indeed be the "Minimum Route Altitude" (Chart Users' Guide, Terminal Procedure Publications, the second page numbered 37). For a STAR this presumably still applies, but the Legend (the page numbered 40) does not show this specifically.

Comment: @randomhead - but since the altitudes (circled in red) are below the altitudes published for the STAR when would they ever be of use procedurally or regulatory?

Comment: That I don't know.

Comment: What confuses me is the minimum crossing restriction of FL240 at BRUEN.  If I’m at FL190 crossing HLYWD do I need to climb back up before BRUEN?

Comment: They are minimum altitudes for that transition route on the arrival.  They will typically not be used on a descend via clearance.  It is possible an aircraft has an emergency (pressurization issue perhaps) and decides to descend to the minimum altitude and then proceed on the descend via after AVATR

Comment: Lost comms maybe?  Lots of IFR trivia only makes sense in that context.

Comment: @StephenS- Good point, a primary purpose of published route segment altitudes like MEAs, for example, is for lost comm purposes (otherwise you're at an ATC assigned altitude or cleared for a procedure containing published altitudes).